# Kubernetes Load balancer server connection refused:Default 80 port is working

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, spring-cloud-gcp

After deploying a spring microservice ,Load balancer in Kubernetes  is not connecting to the mentioned port in Google Cloud Platform.

Is there any firewall settings we need to change to connect to the deployed service ?

https://serverfault.com/questions/912734/kubernetes-connection-refused-during-deployment

Comment: "This site can’t be reached" error is showing.

Comment: Can you share the deployment and service yaml files please?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is an issue with your Kubernetes Service and/or Deployment. GKE will automatically provision the firewall rules required for the ports mapped to the `Service` resource.

Ensure that you have exposed `port 80` on your `Service` and also mapped it to a valid port on your `Deployment`'s `Pods`

Here is an example of using a `Deployment` and `Service` to expose an nginx pod:

deployment.yaml:

`apiVersion: apps/v1                 # API Version of this Object
kind: Deployment                    # This Object Type
metadata:                           # Allows you to specify custom metadata
  name: nginx                       # Specifies the name of this object
spec:                               # The official specification matching object type schema
  selector:                         # Label selector for pods
    matchLabels:                    # Must match these label(s)
      app: nginx                    # Custom label with value
  template:                         # Template describes the pods that are created
    metadata:                       # Standard objects metadata
      labels:                       # Labels used to group/categorize objects
        app: nginx                  # The name of this template
    spec:                           # Specification of the desired behaviour of this pod
      containers:                   # List of containers belonging to this pod (cannot be changed/updated)
      - name: nginx                 # Name of this container
        image: nginx                # Docker image used for this container
        ports:                      # Port mapping(s)
          - containerPort: 80       # Number of port to expose on this pods ip`

service.yaml:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80`

To see what ip address (and ports) are being mapped you can run:
`kubectl get services` and `kubectl describe pod <your pod name`>`

If you are still having problems please provide the outputs of the two `kubectl` commands above.

Good luck!